# Ambiguous step in theorem 7.20 of Sheldon Axler’s Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd ed.

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-operator

[image: theorem 7.20]

Hello, I have attached theorem 7.20 in the link above.
Context:
In the picture, V denotes a finite-dimensional inner product space over F, and F denotes R (field of real numbers) or C (field of complex numbers). < , > denote an inner product. T is an operator on V. T* is the adjoint of T.

Question:
I do not understand how the equivalence in the highlighted step was deduced. How does supposing <T*Tv, v> = <TT*v, v> for all v in V imply <Tv, Tv> = <T*v, T*v> for all v in V?

Comment: That is not what that says. Remember that $||v||^2 = \langle v, v \rangle.$ The crux is to use the billinearity of the inner product.

Comment: do you know what is the adjoint of $T$ and how is defined?

Comment: I’m unable to figure out the intermediate algebraic steps to go from <T\*Tv, v> = <TT\*v, v> to <Tv, Tv> = <T\*v, T\*v> for all v in V. I’m familiar with the definition of the adjoint of T.  It’s just I don’t know where is the gap in my understanding that prevents me from connecting the highlighted steps. If someone can show me the intermediary steps I would be thankful.

Comment: With $w=Tv$, the equality $\langle T^*w,v \rangle = \langle w,Tv \rangle$ becomes $\langle T^*Tv,v \rangle = \|Tv\|^2$.

Comment: You say you know the definition of the adjoint of $T$. But on the left-hand side, the step you are asking about is a direct application of that definition. The right-hand side is also an application of that definition, but used along with the fact that $T^{**} = T$.

Comment: Thank @azif00 and everyone for the answer